# Send an Outlook mail to both people in a dictionary with Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, outlook, win32com, office-automation

I try to send 3 emails,through outlook, to 3 different people (with python 3) that contain pdf file attached. In key 12 I have 2 values, so when i run it while "secNum" variable is 12, the code send the email only to test2@gmail.com and not to test1@gmail.com.

How can i send the email to both people in key 12 using Python 3?

```
    # -*- coding: cp1255 -*-
# encoding = utf8
import os,re,subprocess,time,win32com.client as win32

secNum = input()
dict1 = {'12': ['joe','zeelo' ]
         '14': 'steeve'}

dict2 = {'12':'test1@gmail.com','test2@gmail.com',
        '14':'test1@gmail.com'}
newDate = '27_06'
rootdir = r'F:\desktop\Project'

def data(listName):
    return listName[secNum]
    
for rootdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for subdir in dirs:
        folderPath = os.path.join(rootdir, subdir)
        match = re.search('report'+ ' ' + secNum ,folderPath)
        if match:
            match2 = re.search('2022.June.'+ newDate ,folderPath)
            if match2:
                for fname in os.listdir(folderPath):
                    if fname.endswith('.pdf'): # -------
                        filePath = os.path.join(folderPath,fname)
                        print (filePath)
                        if secNum:
                            outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
                            mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
                            mail.Subject = ' report:' +' ' + secNum
                            mail.To = data(dict2)
                            attachment = mail.Attachments.Add(filePath)
                            mail.HTMLBody = 'hi ' + data(dict1) + '<br> this is report date: <br/>' + newDate
                            mail.Send()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [MailItem.Recipients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.recipients) property which returns a `Recipients` collection that represents all the recipients for the Outlook item. The `Add` method creates a new recipient in the `Recipients` collection. The name of the recipient can be a string representing the display name, the alias, or the full SMTP email address of the recipient.

The `To` field also can be used to specify recipients - you just need to create a string of emails addresses delimited by the semicolon.